# SQL foreign key constraint and dangling tuples

Tags: sql

> A tuple with a foreign key value that does not appear in the referenced relation is said to be a dangling tuple.

I found this in a book. Can anyone explain this?

If we have a **table**

```
CREATE TABLE Studio (
name CHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
address VARCHAR(255),
presC# INT,
FOREIGN KEY (presC#) REFERENCES MovieExec(cert#)
);
```

Then we can't add a tuple with a `presC#` that doesn't exist in `MovieExec`. So how can they get dangling tuples?

Answer (score 3):

You understand it right, what the book is about is a concept that might or might not be allowed in a certain implementation.

If there is a *logical* connection between tables but there is no actual foreign key constraint defined on the database (for example in a staging table before applying detailed key structure), you can get a dangling tuple. While if you do have a FK constraint and it is implemented well then you don't.

FK constraints are just that: way to avoid dangling tuples.

Comment: Or if you have disabled the FK for a certain period of time and then reenabled (without checking the values updated/inserted in the mean time).

Answer (score 0):

Adding foreign key constraints will prevent you from creating dangling tuples.